# simple jquery code is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am binding an on click event on li using jquery. I am just writing simple jquery code when dom is ready. But I don't know why it's not working. I check with chrome or firefox and also there is no console error of js. I am using jQuery v1.11.1

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('dom ready');
    $('#student_list_ul ul li').click(function(){
        alert('li clicked');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="list-inline text-center" id="student_list_ul">
    <li>
        <img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
        <div class="studentname">MICHEL HUSSY</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/girl_student.png" alt="student_image" class="student">
        <div class="studentname">LUSY PARKAR</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
        <div class="studentname">AB DEVILIERS</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove `ul` from selector `$('#student_list_ul li')`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `ul` from the selector.

Should be `$('#student_list_ul li')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#student_list_ul li').click(function(){ // remove the ul from selector hierarchy
     alert('li clicked');
});
```

Or try,

```
$('ul#student_list_ul li').click(function(){ // add ul before ul id
     alert('li clicked');
});
```

```js
$('#student_list_ul li').click(function() { // remove the ul from selector hierarchy
  alert($(this).text()+' clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline text-center" id="student_list_ul">

  <li>
    <img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
    <div class="studentname">MICHEL HUSSY</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/girl_student.png" alt="student_image" class="student">
    <div class="studentname">LUSY PARKAR</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
    <div class="studentname">AB DEVILIERS</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('dom ready');
    $('#student_list_ul li').click(function(){
        alert('li clicked');
    });
});
```

this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code
```

### Html

```
 <ul class="list-inline text-center" id="student_list_ul">

            <li>
         <img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
              <div class="studentname">MICHEL HUSSY</div>
            </li>
            <li><img src="images/girl_student.png" alt="student_image" class="student">
              <div class="studentname">LUSY PARKAR</div>
            </li>
            <li><img src="images/student.png" alt="girl_student_image" class="student">
              <div class="studentname">AB DEVILIERS</div>
            </li>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('dom ready');

    $('#student_list_ul li').click(function(){
        alert('li clicked');
    });
});
```

[check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/mynameisvikram/r10d6kuf/)